# Finding the maximum clique in graph built by thresholding a distance matrix

Tags: graph-theory

I have a symmetric matrix of cosine distances $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Each distance is computed starting from two 512-D vectors.
I want to find the largest possible set of elements whose pairwise distances are all greater than a certain threshold $t$.

The simplest solution I came up with was to create an adjacency matrix $E$ by thresholding the distance matrix, $E = M \geq t$, and then finding the maximum clique inside the graph.

Of course, this algorithm is NP-hard, so its running time makes it infeasible to be used in practice (in particular, $M$ is $15000 \times 15000$).
However, maybe the graph I built has some interesting properties I am not aware of, that allow to find a solution in reasonable time. Do you have any pointers that could help me?
I am also open to scrap undirected graphs completely and solve this with more appropriate representations and algorithms, if needed.

Comment: You mention cosine distances. What is the dimension of the initial space? For $2$-dimensional space you get a [circular arc graph](https://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_133.html) and a simple linear-logarithmic solution for maximum clique problem with the initial vectors, or square-logarithmic without them. For $3$-dimensional space it is likely that there is a polynomial solution, as it exists for [unit disk](https://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_389.html) graphs. (Each vector corresponds to a unit circle on a sphere with certain radius.) For higher dimensions I would bet for NP-hardness

Comment: Unfortunately it's 512-D. I honestly did not think that detail would be relevant, so I did not include it in the original question; I now edited it so it's clear to any future answer.

Answer (score 1):

Cosine distances depends only on the angle, so you can represent your vectors on a unit sphere. Your threshold graph is the intersection graph of the unit disks centered on the point (placed on the sphere).

If your similarity is based on cosine distances in the $2$-dimensional Euclidean space, then your graph is a [circular arc graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular-arc_graph) and maximum clique is solvable in $\mathcal{O}(m)$ (assuming your points are already sorting around the circle) [1].

In dimension $3$, your graph is like a unit disk graph, except the intersecting disks are located on a 3D sphere.

For classical unit disk graphs, the maximum clique problem can be solved in polynomial time [2, 3]. The algorithm in [2] works the same when the disks are on a sphere, it probably is for the one described in [3].

The idea is to compute the maximum clique containing a given edge. By considering all edges, we will find the maximum clique. Given an edge, all the other vertices of the clique must be at unit distance of both extremities, so in the intersection of the two unit disks centered at the extremities of the edge, we just need to find the maximum clique in this region.

Solving the maximum clique is equivalent to solving the independent set in the complement graph. The intersection of the two disks can be divided in two equal parts, of diameter less than the unit distance. So all the vertices of one part are all linked together. By taking the complement, neither of these vertices are linked together. Hence the complement is a bipartite graph (each edge of one part is only adjacent to the edges of the other part). Solving the maximum independent set in bipartite graphs is polynomial (equivalent to maximum graph matching), hence we have a polynomial algorithm.

The polynomiality of maximum clique is still an open problem for 3D unit dis balls, and it is NP-hard when $d\geq 4$ (see [4]). Because the problem of maximum clique of $d$-dimensional unit-ball graphs on a $d+1$ dimensional sphere is more general than the maximum clique in $d$ dimensional unit ball graphs, the NP-hardness result transfer.

[1]: *Bhattacharya, Binay K.; Kaller, Damon*, [**An (O(m+n\log n)) algorithm for the maximum-clique problem in circular-arc graphs**](https://doi.org/10.1006/jagm.1997.0868), J. Algorithms 25, No. 2, 336-358 (1997). [ZBL0887.68042](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0887.68042).

[2]: *Clark, Brent N.; Colbourn, Charles J.; Johnson, David S.*, [**Unit disk graphs**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(90)90358-O), Discrete Math. 86, No. 1-3, 165-177 (1990). [ZBL0739.05079](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0739.05079).

[3]: *Espenant, Jared; Keil, J. Mark; Mondal, Debajyoti.*, [**Finding a Maximum Clique in a Disk Graph**](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2303.07645), arXiv. (2023).

[4]: *Bonamy, Marthe; Bonnet, Édouard; Bousquet, Nicolas; Charbit, Pierre; Giannopoulos, Panos; Kim, Eun Jung; Rzążewski, Paweł; Sikora, Florian; Thomassé, Stéphan*, [**EPTAS and subexponential algorithm for maximum clique on disk and unit ball graphs**](https://doi.org/10.1145/3433160), J. ACM 68, No. 2, Paper No. 9, 38 p. (2021). [ZBL1499.68256](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1499.68256).

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful answer. Unfortunately I honestly did not think that the original dimension of the vectors used to compute the distance matrix would have such an impact on the solution. The distances are computed from pairs of 512-D vectors. I edited my original question accordingly to highlight that.